# ORM tool for sybase and .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sybase

I am working on an application which is developed in win forms using SCSF. We are using Sybase as dataset. We use Type DataSet to populate data in memory coming from database using store procedure.

So now we are using linq query on it for searching rows in table. I want to extend use of linq and do all the CRUD operation more effectively.

Can anyone suggest what i can use to do that? any ORM framework so that i can use it effectively?

Can Entity framework use effectively on databases other then SQL server?

Comment: Which version of Sybase?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Telerik's OpenAccess.  The free edition doesn't support Sybase but the commercial one does.

http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/free.aspx